# Regex Expression with several different patterns

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm using these regex expressions in VB.NET and they all work separately:

```
texto = "ola <a href=""http://www.aiaia.pt"">coisas</a> tas <object> zborgind </object> bom <iframe src=""http://www.uiuiuiuiiu.pt""></iframe> hoje? <center>qq coisa</center> Já acabou, <script>document.write(""oi"")</script> ...agora!"
Dim regEx2 As New Regex("<a[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
texto = regEx2.Replace(texto, String.Empty)
regEx2 = New Regex("</a[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
texto = regEx2.Replace(texto, String.Empty)
regEx2 = New Regex("<object.*?>.*</object\s*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
texto = regEx2.Replace(texto, String.Empty)
regEx2 = New Regex("<iframe.*?>.*</iframe\s*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
texto = regEx2.Replace(texto, String.Empty)
regEx2 = New Regex("<center[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
texto = regEx2.Replace(texto, String.Empty)
regEx2 = New Regex("</center[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
texto = regEx2.Replace(texto, String.Empty)
regEx2 = New Regex("<script[^>]*>([\w\W]*?)</script>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
texto = regEx2.Replace(texto, String.Empty)
```

How can I join them all in one expression?

I tried this to join them in one:

```
Dim texto2 As String = "ola <a href=""http://www.aiaia.pt"">coisas</a> tas <object> zborgind </object> bom <iframe src=""http://www.uiuiuiuiiu.pt""></iframe> hoje? <center>qq coisa</center> Já acabou, <script>document.write(""oi"")</script> ...agora!"

Dim re As New Regex( _
    "^<a[^>]*>$" & _
    "^</a[^>]*>$" & _
    "^<object.*?>.*</object\s*?>$" & _
    "^<iframe.*?>.*</iframe\s*?>$" & _
    "^<center[^>]*>$" & _
    "^</center[^>]*>$" & _
    "^<script[^>]*>([\w\W]*?)</script>$", _
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline _
)
```

But doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please use the formating tools ? Also you should name your variables in English, well that's a preference ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` and `$` matches the start and end of a line. They do not delimit subpatterns in a regex. Use `|` instead; It matches either the left or right side.

```
Dim re As New Regex( _
    "<a[^>]*>" & _
    "|</a[^>]*>" & _
    "|<object.*?>.*</object\s*?>" & _
    "|<iframe.*?>.*</iframe\s*?>" & _
    "|<center[^>]*>" & _
    "|</center[^>]*>" & _
    "|<script[^>]*>([\w\W]*?)</script>", _
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline _
)
```